# Does AWS Athena supports Sequence File

Tags: amazon-athena

Has any one tried creating AWS Athena Table on top of Sequence Files.  As per the [Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/create-table.html) looks like it is possible. I was able to execute below create table statement.

```
   create external table if not exists sample_sequence (
      account_id string,
      receiver_id string,
      session_index smallint, 
      start_epoch bigint)
STORED AS sequencefile
location 's3://bucket/sequencefile/';
```

The Statement executed Successfully but when i try to read data from the table it throws below error

```
Your query has the following error(s):

HIVE_CANNOT_OPEN_SPLIT: Error opening Hive split s3://viewershipforneo4j/2017-09-26/000030_0 (offset=372128055, length=62021342) using org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileInputFormat: s3://viewershipforneo4j/2017-09-26/000030_0 not a SequenceFile

This query ran against the "default" database, unless qualified by the query. Please post the error message on our forum or contact customer support with Query Id: 9f0983b0-33da-4686-84a3-91b14a39cd09.
```

Answer (score 0):

Sequence file are valid one . Issue here is there is not deliminator defined.

Ie **row format** delimited **fields terminated by** is missing

if in your case if tab is column deliminator row data is in next row it will be

```
create external table if not exists sample_sequence (
  account_id string,
  receiver_id string,
  session_index smallint, 
  start_epoch bigint)
  row format delimited fields terminated by '\t'
STORED AS sequencefile
 location 's3://bucket/sequencefile/';
```